# Concatenating two integer columns works in isolation, but not in a function

Tags: postgresql

Related to my question yesterday which was answered by @a_horse_with_no_name.

The following query works..

```
SELECT 
    CAST(FC.Life1monthofbirth AS VARCHAR(2)) || '/' || CAST(FC.Life1yearofbirth AS VARCHAR(4)) 
FROM 
    public.factclient FC;
```

...but when I have essentially the same code in a function...

```
,CAST(FC.Life1monthofbirth AS VARCHAR(2)) || '/' || CAST(FC.Life1yearofbirth AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Life1DOB
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown / unknown
>   LINE 25:     ,CAST(FC.Life1monthofbirth AS VARCHAR(2)) || '/' || CAST...
>                                                              ^
>   HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I don't understand why the first scenario works, but the second one doesn't. I'm using Postgres version 12 and writing my queries using pgAdmin 4.13

I have added the complete function code below. Apologies if it is not very readable.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.postgres_termpositionrawdata_ver2(
    p_provider character varying,
    p_date date,
    p_correlationid character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
    p_type character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    p_productexclusionset character varying DEFAULT 'LevelTermPosition'::character varying,
    p_ctmoptions character varying DEFAULT 'WOM'::character varying,
    p_test character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_testaccountlogon character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    p_averagetopx integer DEFAULT 5,
    p_filterquote integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
    p_includeduplicatequotes character varying DEFAULT 'Yes'::character varying,
    p_ignoreglobalpermissions character varying DEFAULT 'Yes'::character varying,
    p_ignoredefaultproductexclusions character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_ignorelowstartresponseindicator character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_ignorevariableresponseindicator character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$

    --DECLARE CONSTANTS
    DECLARE  

    --DECLARE VARIABLES 
 v_Status  varchar(10) = 'Success';BEGIN
  -- assume success

    -- SET CorrelationID
    IF p_CorrelationId IS NULL THEN p_CorrelationId := public.swf_newid();

    END IF; 



         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredRequests;
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredResponses;
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ranks;    




     CREATE TEMP TABLE FilteredRequests AS

        SELECT * FROM public.dblink('srv_exchangemart',
           'SELECT
                 FRQ.QuoteID                    
                ,DEO.Name                                   AS      OrganisationName
                ,DEO.Postcode                               AS      OrganisationPostcode
                ,DEO.FRN                                    AS      OrganisationFRN
                ,DDQ.Date                                   AS      RequestDate
                ,DLB.LifeBasis                          
                ,DDC.Date                                   AS      CommencementDate
                ,CASE   
                    WHEN FRQ.Term <> 0
                        THEN CAST (FRQ.Term AS Varchar(5)) ||  "Years"
                    WHEN FRQ.TermToAge <> 0
                        THEN "To Age " || CAST(FRQ.TermToAge AS Varchar(5))                 
                    ELSE "Unknown"
                END                                         AS      PolicyTerm
                ,DQF.QuotationFor                       
                ,LCR.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationship            
                ,TDP.TotalPermanentDisabilityCover              
                ,CB.CommissionBasis
                ,DCT.CommissionType
                ,DG1.Gender                                 AS      Life1Gender
                ,CONCAT_WS('|', FC.Life1MonthOfBirth, FC.Life1YearOfBirth)      AS      Life1DOB
                ,FC.Life1Age                                AS      Life1Age
                ,FC.Life1QuarterlyAge                           
                ,DS1.Smoker                                 AS      Life1Smoker
                ,DO1.Occupation                             AS      Life1Occupation
                ,DG2.Gender                                 AS      Life2Gender
                ,CONCAT_WS('|', FC.Life2MonthOfBirth, FC.Life2YearOfBirth)      AS      Life2DOB            
                ,FC.Life2Age                                AS      Life2Age
                ,FC.Life2QuarterlyAge                               
                ,DS2.Smoker                                 AS      Life2Smoker
                ,DO2.Occupation                             AS      Life2Occupation
                ,DEP.PanelId                                        
                FROM ExchangeMart.dbo.FactRequest FRQ   
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimExchangeOrganisation DEO ON FRQ.ExchangeOrganisationID = DEO.ExchangeOrganisationId
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimExchangeUser DEU ON FRQ.ExchangeUserId = DEU.ExchangeUserId
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimLifeBasis DLB ON FRQ.LifeBasisId = DLB.LifeBasisID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimTotalPermanentDisabilityCover TDP ON FRQ.TotalPermanentDisabilityCoverId = TDP.TotalPermanentDisabilityCoverID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimDate DDQ ON FRQ.QuotationDateID = DDQ.DateID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimDate DDC ON FRQ.CommencementDateID = DDC.DateID  
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimExchangePanel DEP ON FRQ.ExchangePanelId = DEP.ExchangePanelId           
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimCommissionBasis CB   ON FRQ.CommissionBasisId = CB.CommissionBasisId
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimCommissionType DCT   ON FRQ.CommissionTypeId = DCT.CommissionTypeId  
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.factClient FC   ON FRQ.QuoteID = FC.QuoteID 
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimLifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationship LCR ON FRQ.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationshipId = LCR.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationshipId
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimQuotationFor DQF ON FRQ.QuotationForId = DQF.QuotationForId              
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimKeyPerson DKP ON FRQ.KeyPersonId = DKP.KeyPersonId       
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimBenefitBasis DBB ON FRQ.BenefitBasisId = DBB.BenefitBasisId      
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimIntegrator DI ON FRQ.ExchangeIntegratorId = DI.ExchangeIntegratorId                                                          
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimGender DG1   ON FC.Life1GenderID = DG1.GenderID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimGender DG2   ON FC.Life2GenderID = DG2.GenderID                      
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimSmoker DS1 ON FC.Life1SmokerID = DS1.SmokerID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimSmoker DS2   ON FC.Life2SmokerID = DS2.SmokerID              
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimOccupation DO1   ON FC.Life1OccupationId = DO1.OccupationID
                INNER JOIN ExchangeMart.dbo.dimOccupation DO2   ON FC.Life2OccupationId = DO2.OccupationID  



               WHERE DDQ.Date = p_Date
                 AND FRQ.ProductTypeId IN (53)  -- TERM ONLY                 
                 AND KeyPerson = "No" -- Not Business 
                 AND DBB.BenefitBasis = "Benefit Led" -- ONLY RETURNS BENEFIT LED QUOTES      

                 AND (DEU.LogonId = p_TestAccountLogon OR   (p_TestAccountLogon IS NULL
                                                        AND DI.DefaultExclusion = "No"
                                                        AND DEO.DefaultExclusion = "No"))
                AND (      (p_IncludeDuplicateQuotes = "No" AND FRQ.IsDuplicateQuote = 0) 
                        OR (p_IncludeDuplicateQuotes = "Yes"))
                AND (FRQ.QuoteId = p_FilterQuote OR p_FilterQuote IS NULL)

                AND (   (p_CTMOptions = "CTM Only" AND DEU.LogonId = "CTM000")
                    OR  (p_CTMOptions = "Exclude CTM" AND DEU.LogonId != "CTM000")
                    OR  (p_CTMOptions = "WOM")
                    )
            ')
    AS DATA(QuoteID INTEGER, OrganisationName character varying, OrganisationPostcode character varying, OrganisationFRN character varying
            , RequestDate date, LifeBasis character varying, CommencementDate date, PolicyTerm character varying, QuotationFor character varying
            , LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationship character varying, TotalPermanentDisabilityCover character varying, COmmissionBasis character varying
            , CommisionType character varying, Life1Gender character varying, Life1DOB character varying, Life1Age INTEGER, Life1QuarterlyAge numeric(12,2)
            , Life1Smoker character varying, Life1Occupation character varying, Life2Gender character varying, Life2Age INTEGER 
            , Life2QuarterlyAge numeric(12,2), Life2Smoker character varying, Life2Occupation character varying);

            SELECT * FROM FilteredRequests;

        END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Use `concat()` or `concat_ws()` - those functions are more lenient with casting.

Comment: Yes, I did try using concat_ws and I got exactly the same error. Could it be something to do with the fact that I am using dblink for my query?  So the function that includes the problematic bit of code  connects to a Foreign Server via dblink.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9edd96bfa969efc7b5a863991ed4f1b8  - But you seem to have a a quoting issue there as the error message indicates it's trying to divide. So probably your `'/'` is somehow interpreted as `/`

Comment: Yes, I thought that, so I tried using '-', '--' and '|', but still got the same error.

Comment: Use dollar quoting: `dblink('srv_exchangemart', $sql$ SELECT ..... $sql$)` then you don't have problems with embedded single quotes. Do you really have a columns named `"No"` and `"Yes"` - if those should be constant values, you need single quotes for them `'No'` is a string constant `"No"` is an identifier (column name)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. :No' and 'Yes' are default values for some input parameters. Ah, I see what you mean further down the function in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I now get a different error...ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "exchangemart.dbo.factrequest"

Comment: Well, that's a completely different error - and the error explains it: you can't reference tables from a different database in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you are **dividing** two items, while your intent is to **concatenate** them.

It implies that you are running this query using `EXECUTE`, so the query text is build then run, and the result of the concatenation you wrote is executed, leading to the unexpected division.

You would have to transform the query so that the result of the concatenation - which will be executed - is the desired concatenation. Something like:

```sql
EXECUTE 'select fieldA' || '||''/''||' || 'fieldB from myTable';
```

Comment: I'm using SELECT to call the function.